# 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java

I just started learning `java` at tutorials point, but getting this common error.

'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: your java pathname not set check http://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-path-in-java

Comment: if my comment solved your problem then you should probably mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the JDK folder to your PATH variable.

Here is how you do it (from the Oracle site):

> Setting Path on Windows
>
> Windows 8
>
> Drag the Mouse pointer to the Right bottom corner of the screen
>      Click on the Search icon and type: Control Panel
>      Click on -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced
>      Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
>      In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
>       Close the window.
>       Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.
>
> Windows 7
>
> Select Computer from the Start menu
>       Choose System Properties from the context menu
>       Click Advanced system settings > Advanced tab
>       Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
>       In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
>       Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.
>
> Windows XP
>
> Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced
>       Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
>       In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
>       Close the window.
>       Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.
>
> Windows Vista
>
> Right click My Computer icon
>       Choose Properties from the context menu
>       Click Advanced tab (Advanced system settings link in Vista)
>       In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location of the class as the value.
>       Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.
>
> On Linux/Solaris:
>
> For bash Shell:
>
> Edit the startup file (~/ .bashrc)
>       Modify PATH variable:
>       PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/jdk1.6.0/bin
>       export PATH
>       Save and close the file
>       Open new Terminal window
>       Verify the PATH is set properly
>       % java -version
>
> For C Shell (csh):
>
> Edit startup file (~/ .cshrc)
>       Set Path
>       set path="$PATH":/usr/local/jdk1.6.0/bin
>       Save and Close the file
>       Open new Terminal window
>       Verify the PATH is set properly
>       % java -version

Comment: Thanks duck42 this helped me but sorry i can't vote ya ' cause i m new here.

Comment: mark obvious duplicates as such, do not answer them again